# Finding an object in a Json array by elemnt

Tags: angularjs

Let's say my JSON response looks like this:

```
{_id: Object, 
foo: [
  object0: {
      content: "ipsum",
      bar: true,
  },
  object1: {
      content: "ipsum",
      bar: false
  }  
]
```

How would I display the `object` with the `bar` that is `true`?

(Something like `{{response.object.where(bar === true).content}}` )

Comment: Generally speaking, you could always loop through the objects until you find one where `bar === true`. But there could be a better way to do it, so I'll wait to see if anyone else answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `foo` is an array of objects, looping and checking is probably your best bet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.foo.length; i++) {
    if (obj.foo[i].hasOwnProperty("bar") {
        if (obj.foo[i].bar == true) {
            //obj.foo[i].bar is true, do something!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

tymeJV's answer is technically the correct answer. In addition to that, I would recommend you start using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) as a general purpose library.

For example, using lodash to find bar:

```
var barObject = _.find(obj.foo, { bar: true });
if (barObject) {
    // Do your thing
}
```